# Use local npm package within a different local npm package

Tags: javascript, architecture, package, directory-structure

I have two React/TypeScript packages that I'm developing, `Grid` and `App`. Internally, `Grid` is a dependency to `App`. Both of these packages have `.tsx` and `.css` files, but are in different folder structures due to the constraints of each project... aka, the relative path of the `css` and `src` files in each project is different. Each package is inside a single folder in my monorepo.

Here's what I'm looking for:

1. I want `Grid` to be in it's own folder. I want to be able to keep it totally separate from `App`.
2. I want to be able to edit `Grid` files while working on `App`, save them, and have my webpack watch command automatically recompile with the changed `Grid` files.
3. I want to be able to import types, function, etc from `Grid` into `App`.

Is there a folder structure I can use that will easily do this? I know I can probably do something with `soft linking` the files, but I'm new to that, so any direction would be greatly appreciated.

This needs to work on both Mac, Linux, and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `npm link` in the node app that you want to use as a package, and then
`npm link name` in the project where you want to use linked app. Name is the name of the linked package (the one in package.json)